# How can I use css and html to make checkmark boxes?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a checkmark box to the right of each of my topic rectangle. I want the box to be about an inch in width, white in color, and have a blue color when it is clicked.

How can I make the right changes in my html and css to solve this? I made a checkbox, but I am struggling to use css to manipulate the checkboxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select a Topic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_landingpage.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Select a Topic</h1>
    <label>
      <input class="checkboxid" type="checkbox" name="topic">
      <a href="game.html?topic=movies">
        <button>Movies</button>
      </a>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input for="checkboxid1" class="checkboxid"  type="checkbox" name="topic">
      <a href="game.html?topic=music">
        <button>Music</button>
      </a>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input class="checkboxid"  type="checkbox" name="topic">
      <a href="game.html?topic=countries">
        <button>Countries</button>
      </a>
    </label>
    <a href="game.html?topic=countries">
      <button class="play-btn">Play</button>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background-color: black;
      color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  }


button {
  display: block;
  width: 2in;
  height: 1in;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play-btn {
  width: 2in;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #006400;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


input {
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px white;
  background-color: #006400 !important;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100px;
}

#checkboxid1 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<button>` elements can't be inside of `<a>` elements.

Comment: There aren't many options to adjust the default checkbox, that's why most tutorials just hide the default box and then create their own custom graphics. You can look at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

first: its wrong put button tag inside a tag.
also, you can use `display:flex` to put checkbox position next to topic rectangle horizontally.

```css
label{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-top:5px;
}
a {
  display:flex;
      align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 2in;
  height: 1in;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
   accent-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 1in;
  height: 1in;
 cursor:pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select a Topic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_landingpage.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Select a Topic</h1>
    <label>
     
      <a href="game.html?topic=movies">
        Movies
      </a>
       <input class="checkboxid" type="checkbox" name="topic">
    </label>
    <label>
      <a href="game.html?topic=music">
        Music
      </a>
      <input for="checkboxid1" class="checkboxid"  type="checkbox" name="topic">
      
    </label>
    <label>
      
      <a href="game.html?topic=countries">
        Countries
      </a>
      <input class="checkboxid"  type="checkbox" name="topic">
    </label>
    <label>
    <a href="game.html?topic=countries">
      Play
    </a>
    </label>
  </body>
</html>
```